# Use equalizer and an usb audio card

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa

I have Raspbian installed on my Rasperry Pi. I have a Delock USB Audio Card and setted it up, works good. My speaker set has a quite strong bass, so I need an equalizer.

There is an alsa plugin which gives me an equalizer, but it doesn't change the usb card sound. If I set the equalizer output as first output, I can't hear anything. I also tried "pulseaudio", but I don't get ho to set it up.

I'm not very familiar with such programs and quite new to Linux. I used this tutorial to set up the usb audio card: http://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/using-a-usb-audio-device-with-a-raspberry-pi--mac-55876

Can someone help me to install an equalizer?

edit: 
At first I installed the alsa equal plugin. I added the asound.conf file:

```
ctl.equal {
type equal;
controls "/home/pi/.alsaequal.bin"
}

pcm.plugequal {
type equal;
slave.pcm "plughw:1,0";
controls "/home/pi/.alsaequal.bin"
}

pcm.equal {
type plug;
slave.pcm plugequal;
}
```

When I type ´alsamixer -D equal´ an equalizer shows up, but changing the values has no effects. I tried to change the line

```
pcm.equal {
```

to

```
pcm.!default {
```

and rebooted, but then I couldn't hear anything. That's where I am right now.

Comment: Explain which part of the instructions you don't understand, then we can help you over that hump.

Comment: @XTian I edited my question

Comment: I have the same question like you, doy you have already found an answer to this?

Comment: @Codebeat No I havn't. I used some other device to play the music from.